# How to access the value of file input?

Tags: magento, cs-cart

I just need a little help in accessing the file input value. I am using a CSCART appliacation. It is just like Magento. My problem is I created 3 file inputs with unique name. And everytime I passed their values to the array. But when i checked the array values. The 3 file inputs is missing. But when I change the file input to textbox. I can access it. I just don't know where's the error in my code. Here it is.

```
//the company_data[contractor_data][banner] is the name of my file
    <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td colspan="3"><input type="file" name="company_data[contractor_data][banner]" id="banner" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td colspan="3"><span style="color:#9c3535; font-size:12px">(must be 576x72 px : JPG,PNG or GIF)</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="text_a" class="cm-trim">{'Text Information'}:</label></td>
                <td colspan="3"><textarea id="text_a" name="company_data[contractor_data][banner_text]" cols="55" rows="8" class="cm-wysiwyg input-textarea-long">{$company_data.banner_text}</textarea></td>
            </tr>
.....
```

In my function

```
function fn_save_contractor_data($company_id = 0,$contractor_data = array()){

if(empty($contractor_data) || $company_id == 0){
    return false;
}

fn_print_die($contractor_data); //this will print all my form values

if(db_get_field("SELECT COUNT(company_id) FROM ?:contractors WHERE company_id = ?i",$company_id) > 0 ){
    return db_query("UPDATE ?:contractors SET ?u WHERE company_id = ?i",$contractor_data,$company_id);
}else{
    $contractor_data['company_id'] = $company_id;
    return db_query("INSERT INTO ?:contractors ?e",$contractor_data);
}
```

}

An the output is:

```
    Array
(
    [shop_tel] => 091254515421
    [shop_holiday] => Regular Holiday
    [shop_business_hours] => Business Hours
    [contractor_name] => San Miguel Cor.
    [representative_firstname] => Danding1
    [representative_lastname] => Cojuangco
    [contractor_tel] => 1234343
    [contractor_cellphone] => 098712
    [contractor_fax] => fax
    [contractor_email] => dennis@tavolozza.ph
    [contractor_website] => 
    [contractor_building] => 
    [contractor_address] => address
    [contractor_city] => town
    [contractor_country] => PH
    [contractor_state] => MNL
    [contractor_zipcode] => 1234
    [bank_name] => PNB
    [branch] => branch
    [bank_account_name] => account
    [account_number] => account number
    [opening_date] => 1357228800
    [is_credit_card] => Y
    [is_vat_included] => I
    [point_ratio] => 1
    [is_back_order] => Y
    [is_international_shipping] => Y
    [free_shipping_amount] => 100.00
    [return] => Y
    [return_day] => 7
    [has_gift_wrapping] => Y
    [has_gift_card] => Y
    [has_message] => Y
    [usergroup_ids] => 0
    [feature_comparison] => Y
    [company_description] => 
    [banner_text] => banner test  //this will be the place where the banner should be.
    [sign_a_text] => sign a.1
    [sign_b_text] => sign b.1.2
)
```

Ok that's my code. Sorry for my confusing question but I hope you can give me any idea. I can't spot my error. This is the first time I used this application. So I am having a hard time debugging it.

Comment: hello check add enctype attribute something like this <form enctype="multipart/form-data attribute">

Comment: ok there is an enctype attribute

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the global array $_FILES to access the uploaded files.

As an example - see the function `fn_attach_image_pairs`. This function calls `fn_filter_uploaded_data`. You may use this function to manipulate files you uploading.